# Content Manager Explorer not loading in IE browser after adding UI Model extensions

Tags: web8.5, cme, gui-extensions

I am using SDL Web 8.5 after adding a UI model extension in the `System.config` file located in `%Tridion Home%\ Web\web\WebUI\WebRoot\Configuration\` The CM is unable to load in Internet Explorer version 11 however the CM loads in Chrome and Firefox browsers.

When I inspect the network tab I see a few 401 errors there.
[image: Errors in the Network tab]
There are no errors in the console tab.

I also made sure to configure [the browser for the Content Manager](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v5&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-B0393E1F-2F38-4CC0-841C-44D78AAE0B33&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-5E34CEE7-158B-4359-8159-B883D0215B4B.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-B0393E1F-2F38-4CC0-841C-44D78AAE0B33&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20Web-v5%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3DConfiguring%2520your%2520Web%2520browser%2520for%2520Content%2520Manager%2520Explorer&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1497959936940&currentQuery=Configuring%2520your%2520Web%2520browser%2520for%2520Content%2520Manager%2520Explorer&currentScope=)

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you seeing the same URL requests (but successful) in other browsers?
Have you any plugins installed on browsers that my be effecting this?
Assuming you've cleared cache for the CM and in the browsers?
What is the GUI extension doing in general?

Comment: the same URL requests are successful in Chrome and firefox. I cleared cache for them CM in the IE browser as well as disabling all the addons but that didn't fix the issue. The UI Model extension displays a warning notification when a component is saved with unwanted strings.

Comment: I could be issue with somewhere tagged are not closed properly?

Comment: AS per Velmuurgan's comment - IE is a lot less forgiving ... I would check the XML config files (often just browsing them in IE itself will highlight if IE has an 'issue' with them).

Comment: I checked the xml config files i added and they have no errors in them.

Answer (score 1):

One of the JS files in the UI Model had code which included the **backtick** similar to this;

```
 var description = `Item '${event.data.details.title}' has finished with status '${event.data.details.state}'`;
```

I Changed this to the following getting rid of the **backtick**

```
var description = "Item" + ${event.data.details.title} + "has finished with status"+ ${event.data.details.state}";
```

and that fixed it.
The backtick syntax for a string which allows for interpolation of variables within a string is not supported by Internet Explorer 11

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer too! You should 'accept' it too so it is officially the solution to your question :)